scale the size of most optimized Perlin noise math formula
the math formula is located https://www.desmos.com/3d/hez8vzegfn for 3d and my goal is to expand both the x and y direction it should expand more than one there is also a tutorial for 2d https://www.desmos.com/calculator/niwbrfglti?lang=es and I'm able to change the amplitude but it I'm not able to expand the period of the waves when expanding the amplitude, the issue may come from the pseudo random formula and another formula which is a sinusoidal interpolator. My goal is to scale the wave evenly like the scale of 0 - 1.
